# Why do I have to click more than once for my function works?

Tags: javascript

My code is working, however I must click it twice or more for it to work 
This is my codes on .ts :

```
    clickToScroll() {
    $("#ayogabung").click(function () {
      $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $("#5StepDiv").offset().top
      }, 1000);
    });
  }
```

And on .html :

```
 <li class="nav-item" id="ayogabung" (click)="clickToScroll()" style="cursor: pointer;">
            <a class="nav-link">Ayo Gabung</a>
        </li>
```

Comment: remove 1000 and check

Comment: still not works :(

Comment: clickToScroll() {

  $('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: $("#5StepDiv").offset().top
  }, 1000);
}

try this

Comment: Glad it works, you can go ahead and upvote @Theraot, he put effort to explain you things

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why two clicks?

As per your HTML I would expect `clickToScroll` to run when you click on the list item with id `ayogabung`.

Then when `clickToScroll` executes, it will attach a handler for the click event of the element with id `ayogabung` by calling `$("#ayogabung").click(/*...*/);`.

Thus, it take another click on the element for this second event handler to run.

---

To reiterate, the first click result in adding a second event handler to the click event. And that second event handler only has a chance to run on the second click.

If that is not what you want, execute the code you put inside `$("#ayogabung").click(/*...*/);` directly, instead of attaching it as an event handler.

I repeat, the code inside `clickToScroll` runs on the first click. And it adds an event handler with `$("#ayogabung").click(/*...*/);`. The code inside that `$("#ayogabung").click(/*...*/);` will only have a chance to run on the second click. If you want it to run on the first click, put the code that is currently inside `$("#ayogabung").click(/*...*/);` directly inside `clickToScroll`.

---

I hope you understand what I am saying. Perhaps code is clearer:

```
clickToScroll() {
  $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: $("#5StepDiv").offset().top}, 1000);
}
```

On the other hand, you could copy that and understand nothing. Up to you.